# Regex to match (1 or more) php heredocs containing an empty line

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-negation, heredoc

Example text at: https://regex101.com/r/tfYEkO/1

I want to find heredocs in php code that contain an empty line.

I can do that using this regex, but if there are 2 heredocs in a file, it'd match from the start of the first to the end of the second:

```
<<<([A-Z]+)\n.*\n\n.*\n *\1\b
```

So I thought negative lookaheads would solve it, but that doesn't match anything:

```
<<<([A-Z]+)\n(?!.*\1.*).*\n\n(?!.*\1.*).*\n *\1\b
```

I don't think I can use negative lookbehinds with the `.*` in it. I tried the ungreedy flag, but that didn't seem to change it.

FYI, a heredoc in php starts with `<<<` and a keyword, and ends with that keyword on it's own line:

```
$foo = <<<HTML
This is the string that is returned.

It can contain multiple lines.
HTML;
```

Comment: Try `'~<<<([A-Z]+)(?:\R(?!\s*\1;$).*)*\R(?:\R(?!\s*\1;$).*)*\R\s*\1;$~m'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3T3rk2/1). Actually, the `$` can be replaced with `\R` since there must be a line break after the `NAME;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~<<<([A-Za-z_]\w*)(?:\R(?!\1;\R).*)*\R(?:\R(?!\1;\R).*)*\R\1;\R~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e0egif/1)

To make it compliant with the PHP 7.3 [more lax requirements](https://laravel-news.com/flexible-heredoc-and-nowdoc-coming-to-php-7-3) (the closing marker can now be indented and the new line requirement after the closing marker is removed), use

```
'~<<<([A-Za-z_]\w*)(?:\R(?!\h*\1;$).*)*\R(?:\R(?!\h*\1;$).*)*\R\h*\1;$~m'
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e0egif/3).

**Details**

- `<<<` - a literal `<<<` substring
- `([A-Za-z_]\w*)` - Group 1: a valid PHP label (*must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore*)
- `(?:\R(?!\1;\R).*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a line break (`\R`) not followed with the same value as in Group 1 followed with `;` and a line break, and then the whole line (`.*`)
- `\R` - a line break
- `(?:\R(?!\1;\R).*)*` - see above (note that in case of `(?!\h*\1;$)`, it means "not followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces, Group 1 value and `;` at the end of the line"
- `\R` - a line break
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\R` - a line break / `$` - end of a line (with `m` modifier, `$` matches line end, not string end).

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes I changed to: `<<<([A-Z]{2,})(?:\n(?!\s*\1.*\n).*)*\n(?:\n(?!\s*\1.*\n).*)*\n\s*\1.*\n` - changed to the more familiar `\n`, put in the `\s` you suggested, and `.*` instead of `;` because php v7.3 made heredoc syntax a bit more flexible.

Comment: @Redzarf Note that `\R` matches any line breaks, not just `\n` and is thus safer. I suggest using `'~<<<([A-Za-z_]\w*)(?:\R(?!\h*\1;$).*)*\R(?:\R(?!\h*\1;$).*)*\R\h*\1;$~m'`, I added this solution to the answer.